# Troubleshooting almost white screen // http://civicrm.org/licensing //

Tags: angularjs, wordpress, civicrm

I'm trying to create a local copy of a wordpress civicrm installation for debugging.

Now that I have all the files dowloaded and the data imported, browsing to https://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM renders only:

// http://civicrm.org/licensing //

That makes me think it's stuck in js somewhere, but I'm out of ideas. I can't even get to a page where I could enable debugging or traceback. I'd be grateful for trouble-shooting suggestions.

Comment: you may get more eyeballs on this at https://civicrm.stackexchange.com